# Web console for ESXi 6.7 VM no longer responds after patch. Where do I look for an error?

Tags: vmware-esxi, remote-desktop, console

I just updated a VMware ESXi server to 6.7.0 Update 2 (Build 13006603)

I have two (2) Windows Server 2016 VMs which I have previously been able to access via the Web Console.  (Summary view of VM, click the screen, Send Ctrl-Alt-Del)

Since the update I can get the enlarged web console screen, however, sending Ctrl-Alt-Del has no affect.

- There have been no changes to the VM definition.
- I can still use Remote Desktop to reach the server.
- It feels like the web console isn't wired to the mouse/keyboard however I've found nothing obvious in the logs.

Is there something I'm missing in vmware.log that I is going to lead me somewhere?

Is there something I've missed in a release note about a change to...a permission?

Comment: I enabled VBS hoping there was a new security requirement that forced a VBS requirement in OS's that supported it to enable the web console.  No luck.

Comment: VMRC works, but not the web console, so I can access the VMs when I'm messing with the network, but would still like to get the web console working again.